# Looking for expressions like "First sight memory."

Tags: expressions

I'm looking for an expression to describe something like **"first sight memory."**

For example, if I remember the word **interesting** as **intresting**  because I got it wrong the first time I saw it.
And then, I say:

> I always spell it wrong because of the **first sight/glance memory.**

What's the standard expression of that?

Comment: There may be technical terms in psychology, but "first impression" or "initial impression" or "initial exposure" may work. "I always spell it wrong because my first impression of it was wrong."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I know, no specific word for that, so I would rather write it out a bit more,

`I always spell it wrong because I misremembered the word at the first learning`

And if I were you in that case, I'll use other phrase than 'always'... like

`I made a habit of misspell it because I misremembered the word at the first learning`